# Cmake cannot find QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, cmake

I have a simple bouncing ball program that I wrote in QtCreator on Windows a couple years ago, and now I'm trying to rebuild it on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) using CMakeLists instead of the Qt project files. My CMakeLists.txt file (loosely based off the cmake file in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064307/opengl-qt-using-cmake) is below.

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.6 )
project ( BouncyBall )

find_package ( Qt4 COMPONENTS QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED )
set (QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories( ${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} )

find_package ( Bullet REQUIRED )

add_executable ( BouncyBall main.cpp BouncyBall.cpp BulletWidget.cpp )
target_link_libraries( BouncyBall ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${BULLET_LIBRARIES} )
```

Cmake configures and generates the build files without any errors, but fails to compile with the following error:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BouncyBall.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -isystem /usr/include/qt4 -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/home/user/Programs/BuildArea/Games/BouncyBall    -o CMakeFiles/BouncyBall.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Programs/Games/BouncyBall/main.cpp
In file included from /home/user/Programs/Games/BouncyBall/main.cpp:2:0:
/home/user/Programs/Games/BouncyBall/BulletWidget.h:4:30: fatal error: QtOpenGl/QGLWidget: No such file or directory
 #include <QtOpenGl/QGLWidget>
```

I've verified that the file is indeed in /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL. I've looked online, but all the solutions I've found refer to adding `QT += opengl` to a project file (but I'm using CMake) or to not having the dev-tools or qt-sdk packages installed (which I do have).

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to write `QtOpenGL/` in the `#include` directive. The include directory `${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}` should already do this for you. Instead use `#include <QGLWidget>` which will be more resilient to version changes where this file is moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't there a typo in your code 'QtOpenGl/QGLWidget'? QtOpenGl should be changed to QtOpenGL. If you do it on Linux the case matters.

Comment: This was tricky. I originally didn't have `QtOpenGl/` in the `#include` directive (like @Nobody said, I didn't need it), and I also didn't originally have qt-sdk installed. I added the folder to the `#include` at somebody's suggestion online (shouldn't make a difference but can't hurt right?), then later discovered I was missing the qt-sdk. This typo kept the error message the same and hid the fact that I'd already fixed the original problem. Anyways, good catch.